# How to delete all cookies belong to a site

Tags: php, cookies

I'm have not idea about how to delete the cookies, what i have done can't work. Is there got other way to delete all cookies belong to a site such as delete all cookies which in the ukwai1203.000webhostapp.com. Below is the code I'm using now, this code is taken from online, but I'm not sure it is correct way to use. Thanks

```
$n=1;
do{
$cookie_name = 'item[$n]';
unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]);
$n=$n+1;
}
while($_COOKIE['item[$n]'] !=0)
```

The cookies in my browser is like item[1],item[2]..., below is how i set the cookies.

```
 if (is_array($_COOKIE['item']))  
 {
    foreach ($_COOKIE['item'] as $name1 => $value)   
    {
        $values11 = explode("__", $value);
        $found = 0;
        if ($img1 == $values11[0])      
        {
            $found = $found + 1;
            $qty = $values11[3] + 1;
            $total = $values11[2] * $qty;
            setcookie("item[$name1]", $img1 . "__" . $nm . "__" . $prize 
. "__" . $qty . "__" . $total, time() + 1800);

        }
    }

    if ($found == 0) 
    {
    setcookie("item[$d]", $img1 . "__" . $nm . "__" . $prize . "__" . 
 $qty . "__" . $total, time() + 1800);
    }
    }else 
    {
    setcookie("item[$d]", $img1 . "__" . $nm . "__" . $prize . "__" . 
$qty . "__" . $total, time() + 1800);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not delete cookie
But to delete you set cookie with a time that is negative:
`setcookie('name', '', -10);`

Comment: my code: for($n=1;$n<20;$n++)
{setcookie("item[$n]",'', time()-1800);
}